# Regex: Make shorter

Tags: regex

Can this be made any shorter:

```
^ABC-DEF-F1-[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{12}-[0-9A-Za-z\-]+_[0-9]{4}_V1.DAT.gz$
```

It will match file like this:

```
ABC-DEF-F1-20140705-003-140705091256-IRPS-1_0088_V1.DAT.gz
```

Comment: That depends on what it isn't supposed to match... you could use `^[A-Z0-9-]*?-(\d|\w)+_\d{4}_V1.DAT.gz$` if certain things don't matter...

Comment: Is there a reason you want to make it shorter? If you compile it it will be stored in a very compact form. From what I can see it is pretty cannonical assuming you don't want to loosen the constraints a little.

Comment: Yeah it's pretty strict:
ABC-DEF-F1: Must match
20140705: Must be this date format:
003: 3 digit seq no:
140705091256: date format
IRPS-1: potentially be anny combination of letters/digits
0088: 4 digit seq number
V1.DAT.gz: must match

Comment: Depending on your regex flavor, you can shorten `[0-9]` to `\d` and `[A-Za-z]` to `\w`. Other than that, your regex seems like it exactly defines what you need, so unless some of those checks aren't actually necessary........

Comment: `\w === [A-Za-z0-9_] !== [A-Za-z]`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's try.

```
^ABC-DEF-F1-\d{8}-\d{3}-\d{12}-[\w-]+_\d{4}_V1.DAT.gz$
```

Please note that the `\w` would also allow lowercase letters and underscores. If you want to avoid this, use:

```
^ABC-DEF-F1-\d{8}-\d{3}-\d{12}-[\dA-Z-]+_\d{4}_V1.DAT.gz$
```

Comment: iirc you don't have to escape `-` in a character class if it's used as the first or last elements, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: `\w` also allows underscores. And as Adam Smith said, you don't need the backslash before the dash.

Comment: AdamSmith: you're right, fixed. @ooga: Wow, I didn't know that. Just looked up the PCRE reference, it even matches digits (I thought only letters). Updated post accordingly. Thank you both!

Comment: The prob is I need it be 50 chars or shorter. But I don't think there is anyway unless remove some of the 'fixed' parts but that's not an option

Comment: Well, then you maybe should have stated that in the question. To be honest, it's a bit annoying to spend time on solving other people's problems, when they don't even bother to specify the problem correctly.